# Java : check for null in setter using ternary

Tags: java, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

learning Java and in a Car Dealership project.

tring to check input in my setter function for car make using ternary operator, eclipse doesn't like what i'm typing :

i'm a little confused as i want to express the followng:
if Make is null => set to Empty {if not} set to input

```
    public void setMake(String Make) {
        this.Make == null ? "" : this.Make;
    }
```

thanks in advance for the help .

Comment: You never assigned the value . Use `this.Make = Make == null ? "" : Make;`.

Comment: Off topic but variable and parameter names should start with a lowercase letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
public void setMake(String Make) {
    this.Make = Make == null ? "" : Make;
}
```

You want to assign the result of the ternary conditional operator to your instance variable.

And when you want to refer to the `Make` passed to the method, you should write `Make`, not `this.Make` (which is the instance variable).

Comment: thanks a lot, seems i have to look more into how this actually works,

Comment: however now it's working, something strange is happening, the program refuses to proceed unless i input a value and is not setting -Empty ""- instead. any advice?

Comment: @Majd I can't give you advice on that without seeing more of your code.